# Error when creating a new user

Tags: users, home-directory

I tried to create a new user account. The following error occurred when I tried to run `sudo adduser bob`

```
[root@IU:~# sudo adduser bob  
Adding user `bob' ...  
Adding new group `bob' (1007) ...  
Adding new user `bob' (1006) with group `bob' ...  
Creating home directory `/home/bob' ...
Stopped: Couldn't create home directory `/home/bob': Permission denied.
Removing directory `/home/bob' ...
Removing user `bob' ...
Removing group `bob' ...
groupdel: group 'bob' does not exist
adduser: `groupdel bob' returned error code 6. Exiting.
```

Comment: What does `namei -l /home` say? please [edit] your question to include the output

Answer (score 0):

The `adduser` command creates a home directory for the newly added user by default.

The command `sudo adduser bob` returned a `` Couldn't create home directory `/home/bob': Permission denied `` error message because you are already root at the command line prompt and don't need to use sudo to obtain root permissions from the `#` command line prompt. Please close the terminal and reopen it. Then `sudo adduser bob` will run from the `$` command line prompt without an error. If you only have access to a root user account that shows you a `#` command line prompt, then `adduser bob` without `sudo` will work after reopening the terminal or else try running `exit` to try to exit from running with root privileges, but it might just close the terminal window instead because your current user is `root@IU`.

Comment: I used the adduser bob , then again the same error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
sudo useradd bob -m -r -p password
```

useradd is an advanced version of adduser. This example does the following:

`-m` makes a home directory.
`-r` adds to the sudoers file (this is not recommended for normal users, as sudo can break anything)
`-p` adds a password. You can manually do this by using `su bob` and executing `passwd`.